# How can I add a default for a column and update all rows with the default value in a single batch in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, default

I am trying to execute the following code as part of a migration in a transaction, but the code fails unless I put the `GO` statement after the `ADD CONSTRAINT` statement:

```
ALTER TABLE T ADD C INT NULL
ALTER TABLE T ADD CONSTRAINT DF_T_C DEFAULT ((1)) FOR C
GO 
UPDATE T SET C = DEFAULT
ALTER TABLE T ALTER COLUMN C INT NOT NULL
```

If I leave out the `GO` statement I get the following error:

> Invalid column name 'C'.

The code executing the migration cannot handle the `GO` statement, how can I get this to work in a single transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `EXEC` for the problematic statements so they get compiled as a different batch.

```
EXEC('UPDATE T SET C = DEFAULT; 
      ALTER TABLE T ALTER COLUMN C INT NOT NULL')
```

But you can also do

```
ALTER TABLE T ADD C INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_T_C DEFAULT ((1))
```

Rather than doing all these individual steps yourself.

Comment: @michielvoo - The statement is not only close it is exactly correct! `CREATE TABLE #T(B INT NULL);INSERT INTO #T VALUES (10);ALTER TABLE #T ADD C INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_T_C DEFAULT ((1));SELECT * FROM #T;DROP TABLE #T`

Answer (score 0):

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

ALTER TABLE T ADD C INT NULL;

ALTER TABLE T ADD CONSTRAINT DF_T_C DEFAULT ((1)) FOR C;
EXEC ('UPDATE T SET C = DEFAULT');

ALTER TABLE T ALTER COLUMN C INT NOT NULL;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Answer (score -2):

I ended up with this, which does everything in one statement:

```
ALTER TABLE T ADD C INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_T_C DEFAULT ((1)) WITH VALUES
```

Works with SQL Server.

Comment: `WITH VALUES` is only needed if the column is `NULL` and then it looks like your script sets it to `NOT NULL` afterwards. The statement in my answer does it all in one statament and avoids the need to do this.

Comment: @Martin Sorry, it should have been NOT NULL, I have corrected my answer.

Comment: Not sure why I thought WITH VALUES was necessary, just ran into this same scenario on a different project today and thought I'd try your solution again: WITH VALUES is not necessary. Also confirmed by MSDN:

"If the new column does not allow nulls, the default value is stored in new rows regardless of whether WITH VALUES is specified."
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187742.aspx

Comment: Not sure why you are flagging your own answer with "Answer doesn't add any new information, accepted answer covers all."